# trap echo does print not write to console when writing to file

Tags: shell, io-redirection, echo, trap

When I terminate "CTRL+C" the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
function waa(){
    for i in {1..10}
    do
      echo "start.sh: sleeping $i"
      sleep 1s
    done
}

trap "echo 'GAGA'" TERM

waa >> log.txt
```

the trap echo "GAGA" goes to log.txt?
Why is that behavior like that? Very unintuitive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have redirected the standard output of `waa` to `log.txt`, and triggered the `trap` while the script was executing `waa`.  The `echo` is executed in that context.

If you want the echo to go to the *console*, you might try redirecting that to the standard error, e.g.,

```
trap "echo 'GAGA' >&2 " TERM
```

(unless you have redirected the standard error while running the script, that should help).